How to ensure Tailwind css styles are being applied
I am trying to set up tailwind for a basic html page. Seems to be set up properly but the styles are not applied. How can I ensure that the tailwind styles are applied?
Link to repo: https://github.com/rsg71/tailwind-example


As per step 1 of the Tailwind CLI setup documentation, create a tailwind.config.js file, either by running npx tailwindcss init or manually creating the file, that contains:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}


As per step 2 of the Tailwind CLI setup documentation, add the paths to the template files that use Tailwind class names. In your case, it would be dist/index.html:
content: [
  'dist/index.html',
],


As per step 4 of the Tailwind CLI setup documentation, ensure you correctly pass src/styles.css as the input CSS file in your Tailwind command by passing the file path with -i in package.json scripts.
Change
"build:css": "tailwind build src/style.css -o dist/style.css"

to
"build:css": "tailwind build -i src/style.css -o dist/style.css"


As per step 4 of the Tailwind CLI setup documentation, run the CLI command to compile the CSS. In your case, your can run:
npm run build:css



